# Extract information from a web page using Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

I want to extract the review and rating information from a buy.com page using Jsoup. Problem is I can't seem to figure out how to do so because the id for every review differs according to its number. For example review number 11 looks something like this:

`<a id="CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl11_reviewIdAnchor" name="a352496">&nbsp;</a><br />`

`<span id="CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl11_ratingInfo"><span class="blueText"><b>5</b> of <b>5</b></span> <b>Great Product</b> 12/15/2010<br /></span>`

`<span id="CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl11_reviewerInfo"><b>A customer</b> from x<br></span>`

`<span id="CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl11_reviewContent">content</span>`

while review number 12 would have the id: ctl12
How can I extract the review content and rating for all reviews in the page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I hope it helps you and the others which may find the same issue!

You should try something like this:

```
String code1 = "<span id=\"CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl11_ratingInfo\"><span class=\"blueText\"><b>1</b> of <b>5</b></span> <b>Great Product</b> 12/15/2010<br /></span>";
String code2 = "<span id=\"CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl12_ratingInfo\"><span class=\"blueText\"><b>2</b> of <b>5</b></span> <b>Bad product</b> 12/03/2010<br /></span>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(code1 + code2);

Elements elements = document.select("span[id~=CustomerReviews_customerReviews_ctl.*_ratingInfo] ");

for (Element element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.outerHtml());
        Elements spanBlueText = element.select("span > span > b");
        String note = spanBlueText.get(0).text();
        String max = spanBlueText.get(1).text();
        System.out.println("    - note: " + note + "/" + max);

        String comment = element.select("> b").text();
        System.out.println("    - comment: " + comment);

        String date = element.text();
        date = date.substring(date.length() - 10);
        System.out.println("    - date: " + date);
}
```

This example makes heavy use of the Jsoup `select` method. You can find the correct syntax for its arguments in the [Jsoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).